# Problem to show graph in preview mode on in report

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form with a graphic and after modifying a certain field in the form, I change the number of graphic's records in this way:

```
Private Sub text_Cantidad_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    Dim strsql As String
    sql = "SELECT TOP " &  CStr(text_Cantidad) & "Format([hora1],""hh:nn:ss"") AS Hora, TEMP_SET_POINT, TEMP_PAST_2 " & _
    " , TEMP_PASTEURIZAD " & _
    " FROM Qry_Registro WHERE Carpeta = '" & onodo.Parent.Text & "' AND Archivo = '" & Trim(onodo.Text) & _
    "' ORDER BY Format([hora1],""hh:nn:ss""), Right(Format([hora1],""hh:nn:ss""),2);"
    With Me.Gráfico1
        .RowSourceType = "Table/Query"
        .RowSource = sql
        .Visible = True
        .Object.Application.PlotBy = 2
    End With
End Sub
```

Then with a button I want to print a report that has the same graph with the same properties and the same records. If I open the report in "report mode" everything is fine, but if I do it in "preview mode" I cannot change the recordsource property in any of the report or section's events.

The code I have for the button so far is:

```
Private Sub btn_Print_Click()
    Dim strsql As String
    TempVars.Add "SqlReport", ""
    TempVars!SqlInformed = Me.Gráfico1.RowSource
    'Error
    DoCmd.OpenReport "Report", acViewPreview
    'Ok
    DoCmd.OpenReport "Informe1",acViewNormal    
End Sub
```

Comment: You reference two different reports. Report is named `Report`? I don't see any code changing report RecordSource. Did you mean you want to change chart `RowSource`?

Comment: Cannot programmatically change chart RowSource when report opened in Normal or PrintPreview. I expect you get an error message explicitly stating that.

Comment: That SQL appears to be missing a space in front of Format: `" Format …`. So I would be surprised the SQL works.

Comment: Sorry, the different names of reports and the space before FORMAT is an error  when i wrote the question.

Answer (score 0):

The recordsource of a report can't be changed after the report is opened.

You shouldn't use dynamic sql to change the query of a form or report. If possible, use a *WhereCondition* parameter in the `DoCmd.OpenForm` or `DoCmd.OpenReport` statement. If your query `Qry_Registro` contains something like a unique ID, you can remove the dynamic "TOP" part from the report's query and replace it by a criterion for a WHERE clause using a subquery:

```
... WHERE ID IN (SELECT TOP x ID FROM ...
```

Placing all criteria in a variable, you can use that in the `DoCmd.OpenReport` statement.

```
strWhereClause = "ID IN (SELECT TOP " & CStr(text_Cantidad) & " ID FROM Qry_Registro " & _
    "WHERE Carpeta = '" & onodo.Parent.Text & "' AND Archivo = '" & Trim(onodo.Text) & "' " & _
    " ORDER BY Format([hora1], ""Long Time""))"

DoCmd.OpenReport ReportName:="MyReport", View:=acViewPreview, WhereCondition:=strWhereClause
```

Comment: I think OP referenced `recordsource` when `rowsource` was intended.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot Wolfgang, but the issue is change the recordsource of chart in report. I solved placing in the properties of chart a query, then before open de report changed the propertie sql of querydef with the same sql that chart in form. Something like this

```
set querydef = currentdb.Querydefs("query_report_chart")
querydef.sql = "SELECT TOP " &  CStr(text_Cantidad) & ....
DoCmd.OpenReport
```

Regards